# How to set order notes in plentymarket rest api?

Tags: php, curl

How can I set order notes in plenty market rest api ?

```
function setOrderNotes($orderId, $orderNote) {

        // set parameter array
        $params = array('referenceType'=>'order','referenceValue'=>$orderId,'text'=>$orderNote,'isVisibleForContact'=>true);

        // make curl request to get order by id
        $result = $this->_makeRequest('/rest/comments','POST', $params);

        // return order array by order id
        return $result;
    }
```

The above code returns error instead of creating the comment (notes) for order id.  Please help me on this problem ?